# Is there a way to create a field that counts up from 1 or the next largest number?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I'm trying to create a "ticketing" solution in SharePoint Online using a custom list. Right now I have a ID field which will keep track of the ticket number, and I also have a 'queue' field, which will indicate what number it rests in the queue. In addition to that, I have a 'status' field that indicates what stage the ticket is in.

Is there a way to have the queue field automatically increment from 1 from the lowest number of active tickets? My thought is once a ticket is closed, the queue value could be nullified. Then the system will +1 to the next largest number, e.g. if there are no tickets then it'll be assigned a queue value of 1. If there are 5 tickets existing it'll assign the next submitted ticket with a value of 6, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd implement a queue list that states the ticket # that is in which queue, which is a lookup column. A workflow can create/update a new queue item in the Queue list and delete queue items that have been completed.

Alternatively (and not recommended), This can all be in a workflow, get all tickets with a queue present, find the largest number with a loop, set the list item with a number + 1. You may also want to loop through and set the fields of the other items to move up the queue (ex: from 3 to 2 and from 2 to 1, after queue 1's ticket has been completed).